# Repl.it - cannot export table from python to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I currently work on a project to collect stock data and to export them in an excel worksheet as it is simply annoying to copy paste them.
Basically, when I run the script, everything is working well until `.to_excel` function.
I wondered if this library was working in Repl.it as I am working on it.
Just take a look to the code below:

```
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import date, timedelta
from tabulate import tabulate
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openpyxl

price = []
vol = []
tickers = ['AI.PA','AIR.PA','AMZN','AAPL','MT.AS','CS.PA','BNP.PA','^FCHI','CA.PA','CO.PA','ACA.PA','BN.PA','^GDAXI','KER.PA','OR.PA','MC.PA','^IXIC','NFLX','ORA.PA','RI.PA','RNO.PA','^GSPC','SAN.PA','GLE.PA','STLA.PA','STM.MI','TSLA','TTE.PA','FR.PA','BZ=F','AC.PA','AF.PA','SAF.PA']

def volatility(ticker):
  stock_symbol = ticker
  end_time = date.today()
  start_time = end_time - timedelta(days=365)
  end = end_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  start = start_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  json_prices = YahooFinancials(stock_symbol
    ).get_historical_price_data(start, end, 'daily')
  prices = pd.DataFrame(json_prices[stock_symbol]
    ['prices'])[['formatted_date', 'close']]
  prices.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)
  prices['returns'] = (np.log(prices.close /
    prices.close.shift(-1)))
  daily_std = np.std(prices.returns)
  std = daily_std * 252 ** 0.5
  df = yf.Ticker(ticker)
  last_price = df.history(period='1d')['Close'][-1]
  price.append(last_price)
  vol.append(std)


for stock in tickers:
  volatility(stock)

tb = {'TICKER':[tickers], 'Price':[price], '52w_vol':[vol]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(tb)
df2.to_excel(r'path\Inliner_pricer.xlsm', sheet_name='Export_python', index = False)
```

Following is the error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 47, in <module>
    df2.to_excel(r'path/Inliner_pricer.xlsm', sheet_name='Export_python', index = False)
  File "/home/runner/LovableLuxuriousCircle/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2345
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 47, in <module>
    df2.to_excel(r'path/Inliner_pricer.xlsm', sheet_name='Export_python', index = False)
  File "/home/runner/LovableLuxuriousCircle/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2345, in to_excel
    formatter.write(
  File "/home/runner/LovableLuxuriousCircle/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/excel.py", line 888, in write
    writer = ExcelWriter(  # type: ignore[abstract]
  File "/home/runner/LovableLuxuriousCircle/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py", line 53, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/runner/LovableLuxuriousCircle/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 1106, in __init__
    self.handles = get_handle(
  File "/home/runner/LovableLuxuriousCircle/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 670, in get_handle
    ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(
  File "/home/runner/LovableLuxuriousCircle/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 339, in _get_filepath_or_buffer
    with urlopen(req_info) as req:
  File "/home/runner/LovableLuxuriousCircle/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 239, in urlopen
    return urllib.request.urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 542, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1397, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1354, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1256, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1267, in _send_request
    self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1101, in putrequest
    self._validate_path(url)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1201, in _validate_path
    raise InvalidURL(f"URL can't contain control characters. {url!r} "
http.client.InvalidURL: URL can't contain control characters. 'path\Inliner_pricer.xlsm' (found at least ' ')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get any error while running your code? Please add the complete error message to the question.

Comment: I just amended.

Comment: it seems it treat path as URL and it doesn't like \ - maybe you should use /  - `path/Inliner_pricer.xlsm`

Comment: I was also thinking about that but no changes